# Adding object with subobjects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an object that has 2 child objects:
Object is a customer. And one of the subobjects is a Country, e.g.: customer.Country = country;
The countries table is not changable. The customers table is changable. 
I am trying to add a new Customer using EF:

```
Context.Customers.Attach(customer);
Context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Added;        
var newEntry = DbSet.Add(customer);
return Context.SaveChanges() > 0
```

And it worked fine during the first testings. But for some strange reason it does not work anymore: it says that subobject already exists in the database.
What's wrong in this code, please advise?

PS
I've resolved this issue with the following code:

```
 Context.Countries.Attach(customer.Country);
 var newEntry = DbSet.Add(customer);
 Context.SaveChanges();
```

But I am not completely sure if that's correct

PPS
Just tested the second approach again and it failed although it worked fine  just once...it's weird...

Comment: Is there an error with the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an element with sub-elements, the sub elements will be added to the database as well. If you add a new customer with the same sub-elements, EF will try to add the sub-elements again and this will (of course fail).

If you have a sub-element, that needs to be assigned to a new element (e.g. country to customer), you need to load the sub-element from the database like this:

```
Country country = Context.Countries.Find(countryId);
customer.Country = country;
Context.Customers.Add(customer);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I know about this approach but I think it's wrong. We should use either attach or state things

Comment: Why this is wrong? `Add` adds a new element to a collection and internally sets the State to attached.

Comment: I am afraid it will be considered as bad code and this is something I am trying to avoid

Comment: `Add`is the way nealy everybody suggests to use to add elements to EF. There are exceptions where using attach/state might be used, but nearly every tutorial and presentation I've read and wrote used `Add`.

Comment: It's not about Add, it's about the child objects. They are detached and the option you suggested will be considered as a bad code, I am afraid.

Comment: ahh. sorry. But as you add a main object, detached sub-objects will be automatically attached as well. If the child-element alread exist in the database, the error will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

To add an object to a table in entityframework you can do either of the following.

```
var country = Context.Countries.First( x => x.Id == 1 );
customer.Country = country; 

Context.Customers.Add( customer );
```

The just call `Context.SaveChanges()` and the entity will be added to the database.

Comment: No, It will work if the object does not have subobject. In my case, I can not add the duplicates of subobjects.

Comment: @J.Doe I just updated my answer to save customer with a country

Comment: I am afraid this will be considered as bad code. I found that it's necessary to use attach/state things, but for some strange reason they work only once...

Comment: Do you have the link to that MSDN page?

Comment: MSDN says that for a proper update we should use attach/state. In your code, we perform additional search operation, set operation and also our previous operation for creating the Country object becomes useless.